# how to set imageview in bottom

Tags: java, android, video, imageview

i want to set image view in bottom. if possible how to set? this is for my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<VideoView 
android:id="@+id/VideoView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="500dip"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<Button 
android:text="Back" 
android:id="@+id/Button01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is for my emulator screen:

[image]

now my videos play in this emulator...at the same time i want to set imageview in this bottom....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/VideoView01">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: i know but i am asking if i add image view in this xml file...i want to set bottom from the video screen..how to set....

Comment: ok thanks now its working fine...now the image view display in corner how to set center....

Comment: use this property :  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"